# Release source code for client

Tags: release

I'm working for a client on their new website.
It's my last mission, so another developer is going to continue my work after my final delivry.

In order to accelerate the process of "switching developer", my client asks me to give an access of the source code to the next developer.. but as my mission is not finished yet (98% of the website is OK) I risk that the new developer steals the code and the client refuses to pay me.

Is there any tool allowing me to securely give the new developer an access to view my code, ask questions, etc without allowing him to steal it (at least easily) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, this seems more like a legal/contract issue. If the other developer can see the source, he could always duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no: If they see they source code, they can duplicate it.
However, if your client simply wants the new developer to have an idea of how your code is structured, you could send them UML diagrams of the Class Hierarchy and the flow of the site.

I hope this helps.